# iOS - AVSpeechSynthesizer pause and continueSpeaking issue

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

> macOS: Mojave 10.14.4 beta
>
> iOS: 12.2 beta
>
> Xcode: 10.2 beta

I was using `AVSpeechSynthesizer` but below code does not resuming from where it paused.

```
// The pause functionality works fine
if (synth.isSpeaking) {
   synth.pauseSpeaking(at: AVSpeechBoundary.word)
}


// But continueSpeaking always starting from the beginning.
if (synth.isPaused) {
   synth.continueSpeaking();
}
```

How can I continue from where I left? Anything I'm missing?

Comment: try to print(synth.continueSpeaking()) is it true or false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented the following code to check your problem *(testings under `Mojave 10.14.4`, `iOS 12.2`, `Xcode 10.2.1` and `swift 5.0`)*:

```
class SpeechSynthesis: UIViewController {

    var synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    var playQueue = [AVSpeechUtterance]()

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        for i in 1...10 {
            let stringNb = "number " + String(i) + " of the speech synthesizer."
            let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: stringNb)
            playQueue.append(utterance)
        }

        for utterance in playQueue {
            synthesizer.speak(utterance)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func pauseButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if (synthesizer.isSpeaking == true) {
            if (synthesizer.pauseSpeaking(at: .immediate) == true) {
                print("PAUSE")
            } else {
                print("P.R.O.B.L.E.M. when pausing.")
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func resumeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if (synthesizer.isPaused == true) {
            if (synthesizer.continueSpeaking() == true) {
                print("CONTINUE")
            } else {
                print("P.R.O.B.L.E.M. when resuming.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed another problem with the boundary `.word` that doesn't always pause when triggered but when this **constraint is changed to `.immediate`**, everything is resuming from where it paused.

However, when it rarely pauses with the boundary `.word`, it [always resumes](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#speech-synthesis) from where it paused as well.

I don't know where your problem comes from but with the configuration mentioned above and this code snippet, **the speech synthesizer resumes from where it paused**.

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic would be like this since 'isSpeaking' includes both speaking and paused states as document said in below. Thus, an extra check is needed.

[image]

```
if synthesizer.isSpeaking {
    if synthesizer.isPaused {
        synthesizer.continueSpeaking()
    } else {
        synthesizer.pauseSpeaking(at: .word)
    }
} else {
    speak(text)
}
```